# Passing an array of strings as argument and modifying it dynamically within the function in C

Tags: arrays, c, string, realloc

I need to dynamically populate an array of strings in C. Here is the example of my code. Compiles fine, segmentation faults. Is it possible to achieve this functionality?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_FILE_NAME_LENGTH 255

void loadList(char*** files,int *filesSize);

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char** files;
  int filesSize=-1;

  loadList(&files, &filesSize);
  //printf("filesize= %d\n",filesSize );
  for(int i=0;i< filesSize;i++) printf("%s\n", files[i]);
  free(files);

  return 0;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void loadList(char*** files,int *filesSize){
 *filesSize=3;
 //some arry for the example
 char *values[] = {"100.dat", "150.dat", "200.dat"};
 for(int i=0;i< *filesSize;i++){
   *files=(char**) realloc(*files,(i+1) * sizeof(**files));
   *files[i]=malloc((MAX_FILE_NAME_LENGTH+1) * sizeof(char*));
   strcpy(*files[i],values[i]);
   printf("%s\n", files[i]);
 }
}
```

Comment: Did you step through the code in a debugger?

Comment: In `*files = (char **)realloc(*files, (i + 1) * sizeof(**files));` you rely on `*files` to point at already allocated memory OR `NULL`. Neither is true.

Comment: does not 'compile fine'   Rather compiling results in 4 warnings.!   Suggest enabling the warnings when compiling, fix those warnings.  For `gcc`at a minimum use options: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11`

Comment: OT: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc()` `calloc()` or `realloc()` the returned value has type `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code (and is error prone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `*files = (char **)realloc(*files, (i + 1) * sizeof(**files));` you rely on `*files` to point at already allocated memory **or** `NULL`. Neither is true.

`*files[i]` should also be `(*files)[i]` because of [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

You also forgot to `free` the allocations made inside the loop. A fix could look like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_FILE_NAME_LENGTH 255

void loadList(char ***files, size_t *filesSize) {
    // some array for the example
    const char *values[] = {"100.dat", "150.dat", "200.dat"};
    *filesSize = sizeof values / sizeof *values;

    *files = NULL; // crucial for first realloc

    for (int i = 0; i < *filesSize; i++) {
        *files = realloc(*files, (i+1) * sizeof **files);
        // I'm using strlen here instead of MAX_FILE_NAME_LENGTH but
        // you can change that back if you want more space than the
        // strings really need.
        (*files)[i] = malloc((strlen(values[i]) + 1) * sizeof(char));
        strcpy((*files)[i], values[i]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char **files;
    size_t filesSize = -1;

    loadList(&files, &filesSize);
    // printf("filesize= %d\n",filesSize );
    for (int i = 0; i < filesSize; i++) printf("%s\n", files[i]);

    // free what was allocated in the loop
    for (int i = 0; i < filesSize; i++) free(files[i]);
    free(files);

    return 0;
}
```

One note on `files = realloc(*files, ...` though:
If `realloc` fails you've lost the original pointer and will not be able to recover. Either assign the return value to a temporary variable and check that it worked or return from the function (after setting `*filesSize` to `i`) *or* exit the program if `*files == NULL`.

Comment: thank you. Awesome. About the `realloc` possible failure - usually I read a list of files within the function and the strings array is empty when passed to the function; I'll check it after (maybe use the `filesSize`. Thanks again!

Comment: @DudeNukem Glad it helped, you're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

The rule is that a `free` must exist for each `xalloc` call. And using a return value can avoid an additional indirection level.

A first way would be to return an array of pointers if you want to only allocate the used size for each string:

```
char** loadList(int* filesSize);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char** files;
    int filesSize = -1;

    files = loadList(&filesSize);
    //printf("filesize= %d\n",filesSize );
    for (int i = 0; i < filesSize; i++) printf("%s\n", files[i]);
    for (int i = 0; i < filesSize; i++) free(files[i]);
    free(files);

    return 0;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

char ** loadList(int* filesSize) {
    //some arry for the example
    char* values[] = { "100.dat", "150.dat", "200.dat" };
    *filesSize = sizeof(values) / sizeof(values[0]);
    char** files = malloc(*filesSize * sizeof(*files));
    for (int i = 0; i < *filesSize; i++) {
        files[i] = strdup(values[i]);
        printf("%s\n", files[i]);
    }
    return files;
}
```

Alternatively if you want all file name to have the maximum size, it is probably better to build a 2D array to have one single allocation/deallocation step:

```
#define MAX_FILE_NAME_LENGTH 255

typedef char FileName[MAX_FILE_NAME_LENGTH];

FileName* loadList(int* filesSize);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int filesSize = -1;

    FileName *files = loadList(&filesSize);
    //printf("filesize= %d\n",filesSize );
    for (int i = 0; i < filesSize; i++) printf("%s\n", files[i]);
    free(files);

    return 0;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

FileName* loadList(int* filesSize) {
//some arry for the example
    char* values[] = { "100.dat", "150.dat", "200.dat" };
    *filesSize = sizeof(values) / sizeof(values[0]);
    FileName *files = malloc(*filesSize * sizeof(*files));
    for (int i = 0; i < *filesSize; i++) {
        strcpy(files[i],values[i]);
        printf("%s\n", files[i]);
    }
    return files;
}
```

Comment: the second solution (using `typedef char FileName[MAX_FILE_NAME_LENGTH];` is very elegant, thanks!